# Adding direction to undirected graph

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

What I'm trying to do is traverse a known path in a given direction for a given distance.

What I have done so far is build a temp table of the path in the order I want to travel and it looks like:

| edge_id | source | target | cost | geom |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 208346 | 167398 | 50564 | 148.55814507696616 | "" |
| 118186 | 167397 | 167398 | 18.917451445786348 | "" |
| 118185 | 167397 | 97888 | 5.577629837679091 | "" |
| 58802 | 97888 | 97889 | 87.04193787193802 | "" |
| 118187 | 97889 | 167399 | 95.53741276977404 | "" |

now I believe I should add a `dir` and `reverse_cost` columns and set value to something.

I'm assuming I can set the values of `dir` and `reverse_cost` based on the `source` and `target` columns, do I also need to change the value of `cost` maybe invert?

I can not figure out how to wright an update query to add the correct info into the table to then be able to run `pgr_withPointsDD`

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this is not the most efficient way but I have a working example that solves my question.

I update the `tmp_network` table with:

```sql
WITH
direction_tbl AS (
    SELECT 
        path_seq,
        source,
        LEAD(source, 1) OVER (ORDER BY path_seq) AS next_source,
        LAG(source, 1) OVER (ORDER BY path_seq) AS prev_source,
        target,
        LEAD(target, 1) OVER (ORDER BY path_seq) AS next_target,
        LAG(target, 1) OVER (ORDER BY path_seq) AS prev_target
    FROM tmp_network
)
UPDATE tmp_network
    SET cost =
    CASE
        WHEN dir.source = dir.next_source THEN -1
        WHEN dir.source = dir.next_target THEN -1
        WHEN dir.target = dir.prev_source THEN -1
        WHEN dir.target = dir.prev_target THEN -1
        ELSE tmp_network.cost
    END,
    reverse_cost =
    CASE
        WHEN dir.target = dir.next_source THEN -1
        WHEN dir.target = dir.next_target THEN -1
        WHEN dir.source = dir.prev_source THEN -1
        WHEN dir.source = dir.prev_target THEN -1
        ELSE tmp_network.reverse_cost
    END
FROM direction_tbl AS dir
WHERE dir.path_seq = tmp_network.path_seq;
```

and `tmp_network` table now looks like:
| path_seq | id | source | target | cost | reverse_cost | geom |
| :------: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: | :----: |
| 1 | 208346 | 167398 | 50564 | -1 | 148.55814507696616 | 0102000020... |
| 2 | 118186 | 167397 | 167398 | -1 | 18.917451445786348 | 0102000020... |
| 3 | 118185 | 167397 | 97888 | 5.577629837679091 | -1 | 0102000020... |
| 4 | 58802 | 97888 | 97889 | 87.04193787193802 | -1 | 0102000020... |
| 5 | 118187 | 97889 | 167399 | 95.53741276977404 | -1 | 0102000020... |

and

```sql
SELECT pg.*
    FROM pgr_withPointsDD(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM tmp_network ORDER BY id',
        'SELECT pid, vid AS edge_id, fraction FROM tmp_poi',
        -1,
        240.0,
        directed := true) AS pg
```

work as expected.